# Как добавить возможность изменять размеры столбцов таблицы с помощью мыши в GWT?

Tags: gwt, java

Не хочу использовать gwt-ext и подобные ради этой цели. Как на чистом GWT реализовать ресайзеры для столбцов таблицы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть два основных варианта, как это можно сделать:

1. Отслеживать сообщения MouseDown/Move/Up с помощью sinkEvents & onBrowserEvent в самой компоненте заголовка, и анализировать координату если она +/-5 от границы, то обрабатывать как при dnd.
2. Использовать отдельные компоненты в качестве управляющих изменением размера, и поместить их поверх заголовка таблицы, например, с помощью [layout panel](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels2.), и сделать невидимыми (opacity = 0.0).

Второй способ более правильный, он используется, например, в [google-docs](http://docs.google.com) (главная таблица с файлами).

Answer (score 0):

В GWT-2.2-M1 эта функциональность есть в самой библиотеке. См.[коммит от 7 янв 2011](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=9513).