# В чем отличие RootPanel от RootLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt, java

Совсем недавно обнаружила, что в gwt есть два вида рута: RootPanel и RootLayoutPanel. И один и второй можно получить через статик метод get. Я так понял, что RootPanel - это самый верхний элемент моей страницы, а RootLayoutPanel - ее единственный child, и уже в RootLayoutPanel мы размещаем свои компоненты. Так ли это? И еще. Какую практическую пользу можно извлечь от каждого из рутов? Я использовал RootPanel только когда делал [перемещение мышью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2383) (в этом случае если заменить RootPanel на RootLayoutPanel, ничего не изменится).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RootPanel** - это элемент < body >. Он содержит в себе RootLayoutPanel, все диалоги, открытые в данный момент (PopupPanel, DialogBox, и т.д.), а также все элементы, которые добавлены напрямую через getter RootPanel (но это нежелательно).

**RootLayoutPanel** - это самый верхний элемент < div >, во всю страницу, т.е. имеет стиль

```
position: absolute; 
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
right: 0px; 
bottom: 0px;
```

По сути же это обыкновенная [LayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/LayoutPanel.html). С тем лишь отличием, что RootLayoutPanel может быть только один (синглтон). То есть непосредственно на RootLayoutPanel можно [позиционировать элементы](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels). А также RootLayoutPanel используется для отслеживания изменения размеров. Для этого используется интерфейс [RequiresResize](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RequiresResize.html). Совершается обход всех детей элемента и у всех, кто реализовал RequiresResize, вызываем onResize.

Answer (score 1):

Да, RootLayoutPanel кладёт себя в RootLayout. Ваши предположения верны. Кроме отлова событий, эту панель часто используют, чтобы что-то проверить (проверить наличие какого-нибудь div'а, например), а также при начальном конструирровании документа (в случае, если он изначально вообще пуст).